# Vuejs <router-link> mesma rota mas parâmetro diferente

Tags: html, vue.js

Pessoal tenho o seguinte componente :

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'menu1-mostrar', params: {atr: var1}}"> Menu1</router-link>
<router-link :to="{name: 'menu1-mostrar', params: {atr: var2}}"> Menu2</router-link>
```

Não estou conseguindo que o componente atualize automaticamente. Somente consigo atualizar clicando em um outro item do menu que tem a rota diferente.

Reparem que o menu 1 e o menu 2 usam a mesma rota. Quando eu clico no menu 1 e depois se eu quiser clicar no menu 2 ele não chama novamente a rota. Tenho que chamar por exemplo o menu 3 que usa rota diferente e depois no menu 2
Eu preciso que a rota sempre seja chamada independente se já estou nela

Comment: Podes explicar melhor qual é a "user story"? ou seja o que fazes na página e o que esperas que aconteça?

Comment: Eu já vi algo dizendo para adicionar um key no <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view> ou <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>, mas nunca testei. Creio que essa pergunta aberta terá respostas e abordagens interessantes.

Answer (score 0):

por padrão o o vue não chama o ciclo de vida se for o mesmo componente por questões de eficiência.
pra reagir a mudança de parâmetro no mesmo componente você precisa adicionar um watch

```
created() {
    this.$watch(
      () => this.$route.params,
      (toParams, previousParams) => {
        // react to route changes...
      }
    )
  },
```

ou adicionar um guard, nesse link ae ta descrito direitim

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema, mas não lembro como resolvi. Se essa resposta resolver, seria uma boa.